# Change text in TextFormatter results a recursive call

Tags: java, fxml, text-formatting

I have a java fxml application that has a field where the user can put his iban number.

After 4 chars a space should be added automatically.

```
public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change t) {
    String text = t.getControlNewText();
    if(text.length() > 0 && text.length() % 4 == 0)
        t.setText(text + " ");
    return t;
}
```

But when I enter 1234 it returns `1231234`
So I think the change event is also fired when I use the `t.setText`function.

Is it possible to prevent this call or it it not possible to format a text inside the TextFormatter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to append the `text` with blank before setting it to `TextFormatter`

```
if(text.length() > 0 && text.length() % 4 == 0){
        String txt = text + " ";
        t.setText(txt);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Setting it to a variable or giving it directly to the function is equal.